# Shapes become stretched when rotated

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, shader, box2d

I am writing a game engine which uses box2d to handle collisions and then renders all shapes to the screen using a matrix and shader. Everything works perfectly fine until a shape gets rotated, at which point it becomes stretched. This means the graphics on the screen aren't in line with the state the box2d world is in.

Here is a screenshot of a scene without rotated squares next to one with the same squares, one rotated.
[image: Rotation causes stretching]

I'm not sure what causes these problems.
I set gluPerspective like so:

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    float ratio = (float)WIDTH / (float)HEIGHT;
    gluPerspective(45, ratio, -1, 1);
```

I input the transform Matrix into the shader like this:

```
float xTranslated = (e->body->GetPosition().x * 100 / SCREEN_WIDTH);
float yTranslated = (e->body->GetPosition().y * 100 / SCREEN_HEIGHT);
float rotated = e->body->GetAngle();

glm::mat4 transform;
transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(xTranslated, yTranslated, 0.0f));
transform = glm::rotate(transform, rotated, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
transform = glm::scale(transform, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

GLint transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "trans");
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

And I initialized my shapes vertices as follows:

```
GLfloat * verts = vertices;
GLfloat floatArray[20] = {
    -0.5f * w, 0.5f* h, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 
    0.5f * w, 0.5f* h, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 
    0.5f * w, -0.5f* h, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 
    -0.5f* w, -0.5f* h, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f 
};
for (GLfloat f : floatArray){
    *verts++ = f;
}
```

Vertex shader like such:

```
#version 150

in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 Color;

uniform mat4 trans;

void main() {
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = trans * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Can anyone spot something that might cause this problem?

Comment: do you have square pixels?

Comment: I don't know what your shaders look like. But it seems like you are using the deprecated matrix stack for your projection matrix, but use some uniform matrix for the transform. You shouldn't mix those things. But please post the shader code so that one has a chance to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @derhass Sorry forgot. Edited with shader code.

Comment: @Jasen I'm sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. As far as I know I should yes ...

Comment: @user3162904: well. that shader does not use the matrices you did set up in the deprecated matrix stack, your `gluPerspective()` call has no effect, and you don't correct the aspect ratio at all. Strangely, in the unrotated case, your boxes appear as squares. Do you use different shaders/no shaders at all in some code path?

Comment: @derhass I agree on the gluPerspective() call, it is useless. The aspect ratio probably has something to do with it. I suspect it does at least. (The stretching ratio might be the same as the screen ratio) As for the shaders, I am sure that they are indeed being used. I'm not sure what makes you think otherwise. If it didn't work/if I delete the file it will simply not do anything at all.

Comment: @user3162904: What made me considering other/no shaders is the fact that your shapes appear as squares in the unrotated case. I assumed that you draw them as squares in object space. But that might just not be the case. What are the values for the `w` and `h` parameters you are using?

Comment: @derhass Ah my bad, I edited the question to hopefully make this clear. Yes they are supposed to be square. While trying a few things I changed my screen width to be the same as my screen height. In this case everything works fine, so I'm quite sure that I have to compensate for the aspect ratio somewhere. I'm just not sure where.

Comment: Where's the point of rotation?

Comment: Are you accounting for the screen's aspect ratio?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No, and I realize that that is my problem. I'm trying to use glm::ortho to create a projection matrix. I will update when I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problem by doing a few things.

First off, I created a projection matrix, and multiplied it with my transform matrix:

```
glm::mat4 transform, projection, mvp;
transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(xTranslated, yTranslated, 0.0f));
transform = glm::rotate(transform, rotated, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
transform = glm::scale(transform, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

projection = glm::ortho(-ASPECT_RATIO, ASPECT_RATIO, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

mvp = projection * transform ;
```

I then pass this mvp matrix to my shader.

I also multiply the x coordinates of all my vertices by the aspect ratio of my screen:

```
float xTranslated = (e->body->GetPosition().x * 100 / SCREEN_WIDTH) * ASPECT_RATIO;
```

And do the same when I create the vertex buffer:

```
GLfloat floatArray[20] = {
    -0.5f * w * ASPECT_RATIO, 0.5f *h, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Top-left
    0.5f *w* ASPECT_RATIO, 0.5f *h, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Top-right
    0.5f *w* ASPECT_RATIO, -0.5f *h, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
    -0.5f *w* ASPECT_RATIO, -0.5f *h, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
};
```

And tada:

[image: Finally Working]